# Using a 'rank' to return 'top' row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-view

I have a data set that returns clients services, like the table below:

```
PERSON_ID   SERVICE_CATEGORY   SERVICE_RANK
1234        BLOW DRY           3  
1234        CUT AND COLOUR     2
1234        RESTYLE            1
4321        BLOW DRY           3
4321        CUT AND COLOUR     2
4321        FRINGE TRIM        1
```

(No idea why I used haircutting, its actually sensitive data and I just cant use that itself)

So I need to run a report of all Services above, but I only want it to bring back the highest Service_Rank (1-10 lets say, with 1 being the most important)

This would then bring back whichever the highest was, even if that was Rank 3, but that would be what we would class of most importance.

In this instance, I would expect it to return

```
PERSON_ID   SERVICE_CATEGORY   SERVICE_RANK 
1234        RESTYLE            1
4321        FRINGE TRIM        1
```

I hope this makes sense.  At the moment its a view, using a variety of tables to bring the data through, and ideally this would form part of my Select statement.

Unfortunately, I am just learning SQL and as such need as much help as I can get!

Thanks in advance (I couldnt find anything that addressed this issue)

Nikki

Comment: And when you [edit] to add the appropriate tag, please also add, given your sample data, what your *expected results* are

Comment: Sorry Gordon, I have done that now.

Comment: Again, sorry Damien, I have done that now.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    PERSON_ID, SERVICE_CATEGORY, SERVICE_RANK, 
    row_number() over (partition by PERSON_ID order by SERVICE_RANK) rn
  FROM
    yourtable
)
SELECT 
  PERSON_ID, SERVICE_CATEGORY, SERVICE_RANK
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a subquery to get the max rank

```
select person_id, service_category, service_rank
from your_table
where service_rank = (select min(service_rank) from your_table)
```

This would return the two rows with SERVICE_RANK 1.

Another way is to use a window function to number the rows:

```
select person_id, service_category, service_rank 
from (
    select 
       person_id, service_category, service_rank, 
       rn = row_number() over (partition by person_id order by service_rank asc)
    from your_table
) a where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to get it to return MIN in the same way you have used MAX above?

Comment: @Nikki83 Yes, if you want the lowest rank just change max to min.

Comment: @Nikki83 I've updated the query so that it gets the rows with rank 1 instead.

Comment: Ah they both sound great, I am just going to run the query and see! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MSSQL and only want one row:

```
SELECT
TOP 1 
* 
FROM haircuts 
ORDER BY service_rank
```

If you want all rows with the highest service rank then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM haircuts 
WHERE service_rank = 
( SELECT MIN(service_rank) from haircuts);
```